# Casting of pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, casting

Can someone please explain me what these 2 lines mean?

```
short * two_byte_pointer = (short*) 10;

int * four_byte_pointer = (int*) 10;
```

I thought that we can only use `int*` before the equal to sign. But how is it possible to cast a number with `short*`? Can you please explain me how pointers are also casted in C?

Comment: I'm not really sure if they are valid instructions, to start with.

Comment: Pointers essentially describe memory addresses. Casting to a pointer type means "take this value and treat it like a memory address". So `(short*)10` means "10 is a memory address where a value of type `short` is stored"

Comment: I think this will cause a segmentation fault, as you're not allowed to access memory at location 10.

Comment: @JHBonarius - that is definitely true on Windows and probably other modern operating systems. But embedded systems is a different beast.

Comment: @JHBonarius It will probably not cause a segfault until you dereference the pointer. However, it's still UB.

Comment: @klutt: Converting an integer to a pointer is not undefined behavior. C 2018 6.3.2.3 5 allows it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, you're right. I mixed it up with that `p+n` where p is a pointer and n is an integer, must point to the same object as p.

Answer (score 3):

Your code (for example first line) means:

Dear compiler, here is a pointer to short `short *` .
It is named `two_byte_pointer`.
I would like it to have a value assigned `=`.
The value I am thinking of is something else, but I want you to trust me that it is a pointer to short - honest `(short*)`.
The value I am using is 10.

And I would not believe a word of it if I were your compiler or your colleague reading the code. Not without some explanatory comments and a quote from the memory part of the description of your environment.

It might make sense in some embedded environments with memory mapped special registers at an unusual location. Maybe not, see the comments by the busybee below.
I am pretty sure that this is just a very theoretical example and "10" is just "a number example".

The naming of the variables with `two_byte` and `four_byte` is based on assumptions on the sizes of types in your environment. Apart from that I would name it `pointer_to_two_byte`, slightly longer, much more precise (not discussing naming style otherwise here).

Comment: (BTW, I did not down-vote. ;-) You might like to add that alignment problems are possible if the casted address does not meet processor-dependent specifications. -- And such a case is not so theoretical as you suggest. Not every compiler-linker-system has extended features like i.e. GCC to provide clean C solutions to access memory-mapped devices. However, in avrlibc used by the AVR flavour of GCC they use the cast, too.

Answer (score 1):

If you cast something the compiler just takes whatever value you provide and interprets it as the type you cast it to. So in this example it will interpret `10` as a pointer to a `short`. The value of a pointer is the memory address it points to. Using this pointer will almost certainly fail because most systems don't allow you to access memory at such a low address.

Casting a number to a pointer can be useful if you need to do calculations on an address and use the result as a pointer.